# Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent not exported

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the bump API in my app. I import the Bump library project into my project. Does anybody know why this is happening?

```
04-26 21:00:15.828: W/ActivityManager(528): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10072

04-26 21:00:15.828: W/BroadcastQueue(528): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=com.bump.core.util.LocationDetector.PASSIVE_LOCATION_UPDATE flg=0x10 (has extras) } from com.helloworld.utility (pid=-1, uid=10071) is not exported from uid 10072 due to receiver com.bumptech.bumpga/com.bump.core.service.PassiveLocationReceiver
```

Here is the relevant portion of my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<service android:name="com.bump.api.BumpAPI">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.bump.api.IBumpAPI" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I tried to look inside the Android source, and it's originating from here in ActivtiyManagerService.java:

```
// If the target is not exported, then nobody else can get to it.
if (!exported) {
   Slog.w(TAG, "Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=" + owningUid);
   return PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED;
}
```

I'm not sure what the "target" is in this case and what needs to be "exported". Has anyone else seen this before?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `exported` attribute in service tag. e.g. `<service android:exported="true" android:name="com.bump.api.BumpAPI">` in Manifest. Exported attribute means, other applications will have access to it or not (activity/service/broadcast etc). In your code that `exported` boolean is `false` so condition `if(!exported)` is always true and hence the it's returning from there. Make change I mentioned and let us know if problem persist.

For Documentation go [***here***](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html).

Answer (score 3):

Have you registered a BroadcastReceiver as described [here](https://github.com/bumptech/bump-api-android#set-up-your-broadcastreceiver)?

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    try {
        if (action.equals(BumpAPIIntents.DATA_RECEIVED)) {
            Log.i("Bump Test", "Received data from: " + api.userIDForChannelID(intent.getLongExtra("channelID", 0)));
            Log.i("Bump Test", "Data: " + new String(intent.getByteArrayExtra("data")));
        } else if (action.equals(BumpAPIIntents.MATCHED)) {
            api.confirm(intent.getLongExtra("proposedChannelID", 0), true);
        } else if (action.equals(BumpAPIIntents.CHANNEL_CONFIRMED)) {
            api.send(intent.getLongExtra("channelID", 0), "Hello, world!".getBytes());
        } else if (action.equals(BumpAPIIntents.CONNECTED)) {
            api.enableBumping();
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {}
}
};

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.CHANNEL_CONFIRMED);
filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.DATA_RECEIVED);
filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.NOT_MATCHED);
filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.MATCHED);
filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.CONNECTED);
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Also check the documentation for [`android:exported`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported):

> The default value depends on whether the activity contains intent filters. The absence of any filters means that the activity can be invoked only by specifying its exact class name. This implies that the activity is intended only for application-internal use (since others would not know the class name). So in this case, the default value is "false". On the other hand, the presence of at least one filter implies that the activity is intended for external use, so the default value is "true".